# Serving a nuxt 3 component as a web component using nuxt server directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, web-component, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to serve a nuxt app header as a web-component to be used on an external app.
I am trying to use nuxt 3 server directory : https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#example

inside server/api/header-component.ts I am trying to use defineEventHandler, to return the web component
However I am having trouble doing this and I cannot find examples

in my external app I am using this call

```
async function loadWebComponent() {
try {
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/header-component");
if (!response.ok) {
throw new Error("HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}");
}
const scriptText = await response.text();
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = scriptText;
document.body.appendChild(script);
} catch (error) {
console.error("Failed to load web component:", error);
}
}

loadWebComponent();
```

My vite config takes the entryFiles which look like this

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from '../components/TheHeader.vue';

const HeaderElement = defineCustomElement(TheHeader);
customElements.define('header-component', HeaderElement);
```

I can share any info which I may have missed.

In my external app where I call the web-component, it is receiving the return of the nuxt evenHandler, however it is saying vue is not defined which should not happen as it is a web-component

Comment: Why do you want to load a JS file and make it execute **inside** a script tag your self?  Why can't you use ``<script src="...yourfile..">`` or an ``import`` which executes it in its own scope (but since there is only one CustomElementsRegistyr; all Web Components will be available)

Comment: I'm using just a simple html & js file to retrieve the response to see if I can get it working

Comment: I have since changed to ```  <script src="http://localhost:3000/header-component.js"></script>```